# rails drop down how to show selected value while editing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, collections

```
<%= f.input :solvency_ratio, as: :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => 1...6  %>
```

drop down list not showing selected value while editing the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selected` option

```
<%= f.input :solvency_ratio, as: :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => 1...6, :selected => f.object.solvency_ratio  %>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%= f.input :solvency_ratio, as: :select, :include_blank => false, :collection => 1...6, :selected => f.object.solvency_ratio.to_int %>
```

this one solved the issue.my solvency_ratio was of type float and it should have been converted into integer